# Resize EFI system partition

Tags: linux, windows-8-preview, multi-boot, efi

I have a Windows 8 installation on a 500gb hd with the following partitions;

1. Recovery 300mb
2. EFI System Partition (ESP) 100mb
3. Reserved 128mb
4. Primary 145gb

Leaving me with free space of 319gb

I'm planning on installing gentoo on part of the remaining free space and I'm going to use the Linux kernel's built-in stub loader, which requires that the Linux kernel and associated RAM disk be stored in the ESP. I'd like to make sure the ESP is large enough that I can install a few linux OS's using this method.

How do I resize the EFI system partition (ESP)?

Comment: 100 MiB of ESP is *plenty* for several Linux kenrels. I am using 23 MiB of it for my gentoo install.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://forum.voodooprojects.org/index.php?topic=1540.0) post provides the nessisary information, but in summary:

> 1. Resize the partitions using a GPT partition editor. (E.g Gparted)
> 2. Update the MBR with the new partitions
> 3. Reinstall the MBR boot settings so windows can start.

Comment: There is only a protective MBR on GPT disks - no MBR code and no partition information inside. What do you mean by "reinstall the MBR boot settings so Windows can start" - on EFI/GPT there is no MBR involved in boot process !